# using sed in a for in loop to remove words from file

Tags: bash, shell, sed, for, delete

I have a file 'book'(not txt) which contains text. I also have a list of words which I need to delete from said file.
I have written this script but for some reason when I try to check and see if the file was changed after execution I get no changes. I tried outputing the result into  book > output.txt but still 'output' has the same text as 'book'.

The code :

```
for word in {am pm cm words count ......}
do
    sed -i 's/${word}//g' book
done
```

do you have any idea why the words in the list aren't deleted as they should?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables are not expanded inside single quotes, but are expanded inside double quotes. You should go for

```
for word in am pm cm words count etc
do
  sed -i "s/${word}//g" book
done
```

Notice you could also call `sed` only one time and achieve the same with

```
sed -i "s/am\|pm\|cm\|words\|count//g" book
```

Answer (score 0):

If the list of words are really long, you can use an array in `bash` and format it.

```
words=(am pm cm words count etc)

fmt=$(IFS='|'; printf '%q' "s/${words[*]}//g")

echo sed -i "$fmt" book
```

- Just add more elements in the array words if need be.
- Remove the `echo` so sed can do it's job.